# How upload a bitstream in Dspace 6 REST API using curl

Tags: rest, curl, dspace

I am trying to upload a file using the REST API of DSpace 6 using curl:

```
curl -k -4 \
    -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" \
    --cookie "JSESSIONID=E7B87CCFA35FB83670F379072505580E" \
    -H "accept: application/json" \
    -X POST "http://localhost:5553/rest/items/4f7b0dba-428d-458a-854d-141350b9b678/bitstreams?name=Picture.jpg" \
    -F 'upload=@picture.jpg'
```

Sending is done correctly, this is the response:

```
{"uuid":"737b78b7-8369-4b47-a36a-69ddd7f24bda","name":"Picture.jpg","handle":null,"type":"bitstream","expand":["parent","policies","all"],"bundleName":"ORIGINAL","description":null,"format":"JPEG","mimeType":"image/jpeg","sizeBytes":570897,"parentObject":null,"retrieveLink":"/rest/bitstreams/737b78b7-8369-4b47-a36a-69ddd7f24bda/retrieve","checkSum":{"value":"0dec466b8d8546a60f39882f7735f084","checkSumAlgorithm":"MD5"},"sequenceId":-1,"policies":null,"link":"/rest/bitstreams/737b78b7-8369-4b47-a36a-69ddd7f24bda"}
```

But when I try to access the uploaded (Inside DSpace) file it says it is not valid.
Try upload a plain text file and add these to the top and to the end of the file:

--------------------------9406e94bc5f35740
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upload"; filename="data.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

[The file content here]

--------------------------9406e94bc5f35740--

I try with request in nodejs but i get the same error.
Some help ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it using the -T (upload-file) param in the curl command:

```
curl -k -4 -v \
    -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" \
    --cookie "JSESSIONID=E7B87CCFA35FB83670F379072505580E" \
    -H "accept: application/json" \
    -X POST "http://localhost:5553/rest/items/4f7b0dba-428d-458a-854d-141350b9b678/bitstreams?name=picture.jpg" \
    -T 'picture.jpg'
```

In nodejs using request-promise:

```
const rp = require('request-promise')
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const PostBitstream = async (itemId) => {

    try {

        const bitstream = fs.createReadStream(path.join('files', 'picture.jpg'));

        const params =  {
            method: 'POST',
            uri: `${BASE_URL}/items/${itemId}/bitstreams?name=${FILE_NAME}`,
            headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data", "accept": "application/json" },
            encoding: null,
            body: bitstream
        }

        const res = await rp(params);
        console.log(res);
    } catch (err) {

        console.log(err.stack);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For python my solution was not to user files= , but data= to avoid the requests multipart.

```
import io
params = {'name': 'file.csv'}
data = io.BytesIO(open('file.csv', 'rb').read())
res = session.post(url, data=data, params=params, headers={})
```